# How to edit Google Colaboratory libraries?

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I edited Keras `.optimizer` and `.layers` modules locally, but Colab uses its own Keras & TensorFlow libraries. Uploading then using the edited libs would be rather involved per pathing and package interactions, and an overkill for a few small edits.

The closest I've got to accessing a module is `keras.optimizers.__file__`, which gives a relative path I don't know what to do with: *'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py'*

Can Colab libraries be edited? Permanently (not per-runtime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Per-runtime solution***

```python
import keras.optimizers

with open('optimizers.txt','r') as writer_file:
    contents_to_write = writer_file.read()
with open(keras.optimizers.__file__,'w') as file_to_overwrite:
    file_to_overwrite.write(contents_to_write)
```

**>>Restart runtime** (do *not* 'Reset all runtimes')

---

To clarify, **(1)** save edited module of interest as a *.txt*, **(2)** overwrite Colab module with the saved module via `.__file__`, **(3)** 'Reset all runtimes' restores Colab modules - use if module breaks

Considering its simplicity, it's as good as a permanent fix. For possibly better scalability, see fizzybear's solution.

Answer (score 20):

Colab now allows direct access to system files from the GUI itself. There one can view and edit all the installed libraries like one would have done on their pc itself.

[image: Google colab screen shot]

Go to the Files icon in the left Sidebar. Go to the Up Folder. From there go to the path

```
usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
```

Here, find the package and make your edit.
Then restart the runtime, from Runtime/Restart Runtime option in the menu.

Comment: Thanks for this but changes to the file are not saved when runtime restarted. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: before restarting the runtime, you may confirm that the changes you made to the file got saved or not.

Answer (score 3):

You could fork the libraries on GitHub, push your changes to a new branch and then do.

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/your-username/keras.git@new-branch
```

Or even a specific commit

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/your-username/keras.git@632560d91286
```

You will need to restart your runtime for the changes to work.

More details [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support).